# "Security level" field in certificate of completion

Tags: docusignapi

how to assign value to "Security level" field in certificate of completion through API?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ8sS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign a value to this field. This field is representing the authentication used for the recipient(s).

You could use [recipient authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/auth/) methods such as IDV, KBA, SMS auth to add additional levels of security.